# problem with Jquery equivalent to javascript createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate the following code with jQuery:

```
        var node = document.createElement("div");
        node.innerHTML = "DynaColumn";
        node.className = "ui-state-default ui-corner-all";

        return node;
```

this is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
return $("<div class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all'>DynaColumn</div>");
```

The first seems to work fine. I'm not sure why the second isn't working:

The object that will be using this return value is calling it as so:

```
something.appendChild(theNode);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild` is a DOM method, so needs to be given a DOM Node, not a jQuery wrapper (as returned by `$(...)` and most other jQuery methods).

Quick way to get the wrapped node out of a jQuery wrapper that contains exactly one element:

```
return $('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">DynaColumn</div>')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  The jQuery wrapper concept is alot more clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that jQuery objects are wrappers around DOM objects.  To get the dom objects out of a jQuery object, use the get() function.

```
return $('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">DynaColumn</div>').get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `something` is a bare DOM element, then you need:

```
something.appendChild(theNode[0]);
```

If `something` is a jQuery object, then you need:

```
something.append(theNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $div = $(document.createElement("div"));
$div.html("DynaColumn");
$div.addClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-corner-all");
return $div; // or $(something).append($div);
```